# How to fix the search option which works fine in HTML but does not work in MVC View

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, search, filtering

I am developing a system in **Asp.net MVC 5**. According to the requirement, there should be a search option to search by each column. Search option must have multiple text boxes to enter text.

I already developed it in `HTML` using `Javascript`. When I run the script in `*.html` it works perfectly. But when I copy and paste it to MVC `*.cshtml` **View** file, filtering is not happening but the text boxes are there as defined.

Is there anyone who can help me to figure out where the problem is and how to fix the `Javascript` part. Thanks in advance. Below is my `HTML` code.

I remove `<!DOCTYPE html> | <html> | <head> | <body>`tags with their relavant close tags when pasting on **MVC**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>

                <style type="text/css">

                tfoot input {
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 3px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }

                </style>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
                $('#example tfoot th').each( function () 
                {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                } );

                // DataTable
                var table = $('#example').DataTable();

                // Apply the search
                table.columns().every( function () 
                {
                    var that = this;

                    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () 
                    {
                        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) 
                        {
                            that
                                .search( this.value )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            } );


                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

                            <table id="example" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Position</th>
                                        <th>Office</th>
                                        <th>Age</th>
                                        <th>Start date</th>
                                        <th>Salary</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                        <td>System Architect</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>61</td>
                                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                        <td>$320,800</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                                        <td>Accountant</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>63</td>
                                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                                        <td>$170,750</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>66</td>
                                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                                        <td>$86,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                                        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>22</td>
                                        <td>2012/03/29</td>
                                        <td>$433,060</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Airi Satou</td>
                                        <td>Accountant</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>33</td>
                                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                                        <td>$162,700</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>61</td>
                                        <td>2012/12/02</td>
                                        <td>$372,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>59</td>
                                        <td>2012/08/06</td>
                                        <td>$137,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>55</td>
                                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                                        <td>$327,900</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                                        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>39</td>
                                        <td>2009/09/15</td>
                                        <td>$205,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>23</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/13</td>
                                        <td>$103,600</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>30</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/19</td>
                                        <td>$90,560</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                                        <td>Support Lead</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>22</td>
                                        <td>2013/03/03</td>
                                        <td>$342,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>36</td>
                                        <td>2008/10/16</td>
                                        <td>$470,600</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                                        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>43</td>
                                        <td>2012/12/18</td>
                                        <td>$313,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>19</td>
                                        <td>2010/03/17</td>
                                        <td>$385,750</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Michael Silva</td>
                                        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>66</td>
                                        <td>2012/11/27</td>
                                        <td>$198,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                                        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>64</td>
                                        <td>2010/06/09</td>
                                        <td>$725,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Gloria Little</td>
                                        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>59</td>
                                        <td>2009/04/10</td>
                                        <td>$237,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>41</td>
                                        <td>2012/10/13</td>
                                        <td>$132,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Dai Rios</td>
                                        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>35</td>
                                        <td>2012/09/26</td>
                                        <td>$217,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                                        <td>Development Lead</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>30</td>
                                        <td>2011/09/03</td>
                                        <td>$345,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                                        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>40</td>
                                        <td>2009/06/25</td>
                                        <td>$675,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                                        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>21</td>
                                        <td>2011/12/12</td>
                                        <td>$106,450</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                                        <td>Sidney</td>
                                        <td>23</td>
                                        <td>2010/09/20</td>
                                        <td>$85,600</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                                        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>47</td>
                                        <td>2009/10/09</td>
                                        <td>$1,200,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                                        <td>Developer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>42</td>
                                        <td>2010/12/22</td>
                                        <td>$92,575</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>Singapore</td>
                                        <td>28</td>
                                        <td>2010/11/14</td>
                                        <td>$357,650</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>28</td>
                                        <td>2011/06/07</td>
                                        <td>$206,850</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Fiona Green</td>
                                        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>48</td>
                                        <td>2010/03/11</td>
                                        <td>$850,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Shou Itou</td>
                                        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>20</td>
                                        <td>2011/08/14</td>
                                        <td>$163,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Michelle House</td>
                                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                                        <td>Sidney</td>
                                        <td>37</td>
                                        <td>2011/06/02</td>
                                        <td>$95,400</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Suki Burks</td>
                                        <td>Developer</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>53</td>
                                        <td>2009/10/22</td>
                                        <td>$114,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                                        <td>Technical Author</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>27</td>
                                        <td>2011/05/07</td>
                                        <td>$145,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                                        <td>Team Leader</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>22</td>
                                        <td>2008/10/26</td>
                                        <td>$235,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                                        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>46</td>
                                        <td>2011/03/09</td>
                                        <td>$324,050</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Unity Butler</td>
                                        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>47</td>
                                        <td>2009/12/09</td>
                                        <td>$85,675</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>51</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/16</td>
                                        <td>$164,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                                        <td>Secretary</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>41</td>
                                        <td>2010/02/12</td>
                                        <td>$109,850</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                                        <td>Financial Controller</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>62</td>
                                        <td>2009/02/14</td>
                                        <td>$452,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>37</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/11</td>
                                        <td>$136,200</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                                        <td>Director</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>65</td>
                                        <td>2008/09/26</td>
                                        <td>$645,750</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                                        <td>Singapore</td>
                                        <td>64</td>
                                        <td>2011/02/03</td>
                                        <td>$234,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>38</td>
                                        <td>2011/05/03</td>
                                        <td>$163,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>37</td>
                                        <td>2009/08/19</td>
                                        <td>$139,575</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Thor Walton</td>
                                        <td>Developer</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>61</td>
                                        <td>2013/08/11</td>
                                        <td>$98,540</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>47</td>
                                        <td>2009/07/07</td>
                                        <td>$87,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                                        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                                        <td>Singapore</td>
                                        <td>64</td>
                                        <td>2012/04/09</td>
                                        <td>$138,575</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>63</td>
                                        <td>2010/01/04</td>
                                        <td>$125,250</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>56</td>
                                        <td>2012/06/01</td>
                                        <td>$115,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                                        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>43</td>
                                        <td>2013/02/01</td>
                                        <td>$75,650</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>46</td>
                                        <td>2011/12/06</td>
                                        <td>$145,600</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>47</td>
                                        <td>2011/03/21</td>
                                        <td>$356,250</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Lael Greer</td>
                                        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>21</td>
                                        <td>2009/02/27</td>
                                        <td>$103,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                                        <td>Developer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>30</td>
                                        <td>2010/07/14</td>
                                        <td>$86,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Shad Decker</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>51</td>
                                        <td>2008/11/13</td>
                                        <td>$183,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                                        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>Singapore</td>
                                        <td>29</td>
                                        <td>2011/06/27</td>
                                        <td>$183,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Donna Snider</td>
                                        <td>Customer Support</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>27</td>
                                        <td>2011/01/25</td>
                                        <td>$112,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Position</th>
                                        <th>Office</th>
                                        <th>Age</th>
                                        <th>Start date</th>
                                        <th>Salary</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>

            </body>
            </html>
```

I debugged the code in browser and found an error. Below is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Report:117)
at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
```

I have added Jquery library before the DataTable library and the function is also available in `jquery.dataTables.min.js`. There are no multiple versions of jQuery libraries. I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The asp.net mvc views generate HTML markup! Compare the one generated by mvc with your working static version, to start with

Comment: If you doing right, the markup generated by CSHTML file should be same as in existing HTML file. Check the inspector and console in browser tools to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Simple command you can use if you are using chrome Control + U

Comment: @AsifRaza Tried that. It shows me the code I already have. Nothing has changed or no any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Load `jquery.js` before loading `jquery.dataTables.js` and other jQuery-related scripts as shown below:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On the other hand you might also try to use non-minified version (or vice-versa) of the `jquery.dataTables.js` file.