# How to develop a search option to search by column in MVC View table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, null

Is there a proper way to search data in a **.cshtml** table by column. Each column must have a text box.
I tried it with javascript and below is my code. But it is not working. Can anyone guide me to do that properly?

```
        function searchSup()
    {
        $('#example thead th').each
            ( function ()
                {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" id="SupInput" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" class="form-control"/>');
                } 
            );

        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("SupInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("SupTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) 
                {
                    var supname = tr[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
                    var contact = tr[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
                    var address = tr[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
                    var telephone = tr[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
                    if (td) 
                        {
                            if (supname.indexOf(filter) > -1 || contact.indexOf(filter) > -1 || address.indexOf(filter) > -1 || telephone.indexOf(filter) > -1) 
                                {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                }
                        }
                }   
    }
```

I am getting an error in this line `tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");` saying `getElementsByTagName value is null`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide sample html as per [mcve]. Also note you can't repeat id's in a page....they are unique by definition

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery DataTable with Custom Column Search](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) that I integrated successfully to some of ASP.NET MVC projects without no problem.

There is also some other demos, but at first step the previous pages would most probably enough for you.

[DataTable (Server side)](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/)

Comment: I was following the code from [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) web site. Later I found something similar in W3 school and combined both. If I can develop my MVC app search function like in the above link, that would be helpful. But I was getting an error saying `DataTable()` is not a function and I could not resolve it. I posted that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147074/how-to-fix-the-search-option-which-works-fine-in-html-but-does-not-work-in-mvc-v) but did not get an answer. Please help me.